# Does Quora awards points for posts made Anonymously?

Tags: quora

Quora allows us to post Questions and Answers anonymously. Do we get points for that?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [you can still earn credits/points when you post anonymously](https://www.quora.com/Quora-Credits/If-I-ask-a-question-anonymously-do-I-get-credits-when-people-follow-it?share=1).

Same rules apply as when you post under your name.

- Questions - You only earn credits if others follow it
- Answers - When other users upvote your answer